# Loop ansible uri json response

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to fetch branches from gitlab, register the result into variable and loop over the items in other parts.

But I'm getting very conflicting errors while doing this.
This gets me a very proper response:

```
  - name: Get Branches
    uri:
      url: https://gitlaburl/api/v4/projects/topname%2Fprojectname/repository/branches
      method: GET
      headers:
        PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxxx
      status_code: 200
    register: git_branches
```

But if try to loop the result like this

```
  - name: Print Branches
    debug:
      msg: "Branch: {{ item }}"
    loop: ”{{ git_branches.json }}"
```

I get error
"Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: ”
Followed by the JSON content.

And if I try to change to loop to:

```
  - name: Print Branches
    debug:
      msg: "Branch: {{ item }}"
    loop: ”{{ git_branches.json | from_json }}"
```

I get error:
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list

So first error says it must be a list, second says it's already a list, what am I missing here?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried to `debug` the registered variable `git_branches`? Does it have `json` key (a list)? Are you are trying to get the contents of URL and do something with it?

Comment: It was a typo. I'm using the contents yes, the json key comes out surprisingly even though return_content is not set. Anyway, working now. Thanks, need to use this more often :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your code. In the loop, the double quotes is not correct. Hence it is giving you the error. It should be `"` and not `”`. After the change it is working correctly in my local system.

Below is the corrected code

```
- name: Print Branches
  debug:
    msg: "Branch: {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ git_branches.json }}"
```